# Activar botón al rellenar los campos + activar checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario con distintos campos y lo que intento es que el botón de enviar no este activo hasta que tanto todos los inputs como el checkbox de aceptación este rellenos y activado, de hecho si se borra después un input el botón se vuelve a deshabilitar.

La cuestión es que los inputs me funcionan correctamente pero no consigo hacer funcionar bien el checkbox, si consigo que hasta que no lo pulso y esta todo relleno no se activa el botón, pero si vuelvo a quitar el check el botón sigue encendido.

Mi código:

```
(function() {
    $('#infoEquipo > div > div > div > input, textarea').keyup(function() {
      $("#micheckbox334").on("click", function(){

        var empty = false;
        $('form > div > div > div > input, textarea').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                empty = true;
            }
        });
        if (empty) {
            $('#llamada223').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        } else {
            $('#llamada223').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      });
     });
  })()
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución es sencilla, debes capturar que ambas condiciones se cumplan, de lo contrario no lograrás el objetivo.

Lo tienes así:

```js
$('form > div > div > div > input, textarea').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    empty = true;
  }
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    empty = true;
  }
});
if (empty) {
  $('#llamada223').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
  $('#llamada223').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Si te fijas, si la primera condición retorna `false`, y la segunda retorna `true`, entonces tu variable `empty` será `true`. Lo mismo si ocurre lo contrario.

Tu necesitas que ambas condiciones a la vez se cumplan para que tu variable `empty` evalúe a `true`. Puedes probar con:

```js
$('form > div > div > div > input, textarea').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '' && $(this).is(":checked")){ // <- ambas deben cumplirse
    empty = true;
  }
});
if (empty) {
  $('#llamada223').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
  $('#llamada223').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Con eso ya podrías resolverlo.

**Nota:**

Cuando realizamos comparaciones debemos hacerlo usando el operador estricto: (`===`). Porque podríamos tener problemas de conversión de tipos.
Por otro lado, siempre es bueno conocer los valores [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Truthy) y/o [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy) a la hora de buscar elementos no definidos o cadenas vacías.

**EDICIÓN**

Veamos un ejemplo funcional usando JQuery. La idea es habilitar un botón si los elementos `input` y `textarea` de un formulario contienen información o están tildados (en caso de tipo `checkbox`).

La validación la haremos cuando se hace `click` sobre el elemento tipo `checkbox`. Usando una estructura parecida al código que tienes en tu pregunta, haremos la validación de la siguiente forma:

1. Al hacer clic sobre el `checkbox` tenemos 2 posibilidades, que el mismo cambie su estado a `checked` o que cambie su estado a `unchecked`. Por lo tanto validaremos los campos `input` y `textarea` sólo cuando el mismo se encuentre `checked`.
2. Si el `checkbox` se encuentra `checked`, recorremos todos los elementos `input` y `textarea` para verificar su valor. Un `input` o `textarea` sin datos devolverá un valor de cadena vacío, que podemos evaluar en un entorno booleano y devolverá `false`. En cambio si tiene datos devolverá `true`.
3. Si alguno de los elementos **no** contiene datos, establecemos la variable `empty` a verdadero y salimos del bucle (no necesitamos seguir verificando, ya que si falla 1 pues no debemos habilitar el botón).
4. Al finalizar el ciclo, comprobamos el valor de `empty`, si el mismo es falso podemos habilitar el botón y salimos de la función.
5. En caso de que el valor sea verdadero, no hacemos nada, el botón seguirá deshabilitado.
6. Si el elemento `checkbox` cambia a `unchecked` no necesitamos verificar los elementos de texto, simplemente deshabilitamos el botón sin más.

Aquí el código:

```js
$("#check").on("click", function() {
  let empty = false;
  if($("#check").prop('checked')) {
    $('form input, textarea').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        empty = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if(!empty) {
      $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
      return;
    }
  }
  $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miForm">
  <input id="texto" type="text" name="texto">
  <br>
  <textarea id="area" name="area" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <br>
  <button id="button" type="button" name="button" disabled>Button</button>
</form>
```

Espero que te quede un poco más clara la lógica.

**2da EDICIÓN**

Manteniendo el código anterior, sólo añadiremos la lógica para el evento `keyup` de cada elemento tipo `input` o `textarea`. Lo ideal es escribir una sola función que maneje el mismo evento para cada elemento, así no repetimos el código.

Lo que hará nuestra función es verificar si se cumplen 2 condiciones para activar o desactivar el botón. Las condiciones para activar el botón serán: Elemento `checkbox` en estado `checked` y valor de todos los elementos `input` o `textarea` contienen datos (no están vacíos).

Veamos:

```js
const onAction = function(event) {
  let empty = false;
  if($("#check").prop('checked')) {
    $('form input, textarea').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        empty = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if(!empty) {
      $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
      return;
    }
  }
  $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

$('form input, textarea').each(function() {
  // añadimos el manejador adecuado según el tipo de elemento
  if($(this).attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
    $(this).on('click', onAction);
  } else {
    $(this).on('keyup', onAction);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miForm">
  <input id="texto" type="text" name="texto">
  <br>
  <textarea id="area" name="area" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <br>
  <button id="button" type="button" name="button" disabled>Button</button>
</form>
```

Como puedes observar, usamos la misma función y se la asignamos al evento adecuado. El tipo de evento que vayas a manejar ya es cosa de tu lógica, puedes probar diferentes opciones, pero normalmente en los campos de texto (`input` y `textarea`) se usa `keyup`.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario me da error en la línea `if (empty) {`  @Mauricio Contreras

Comment: Dejaste la variable `empty` fuera? Yo solo copié el código que debes cambiar. Tu declaración de variable `var empty = false;` debes mantenerla, de lo contrario cómo la evalúas si no la defines?

Comment: No entiendo, soy bastante nuevo en esto. Me explicas por favor?

Comment: Lo añadi a lo que tenia @Mauricio Contreras , pero me sigue sucediendo igual, es decir funciona la primera vez que pulso

Comment: Ya te muestro un ejemplo, de paso, disculpa que te diga esto: *evita JQuery* en lo posible.

Comment: OK! espero el ejemplo @Mauricio Contreras , de momento estoy como al principio pero con un código más limpio. Ya me dices también por que evitar JQuery

Comment: Creo que puede ser que cumplo el objetivo como tu dices y por eso se activa el botón, pero si depues de cumplirlo borro un campo o desmarco el check no se desactiva el botón, es decir algo esta mal, por que cuando tenia solo lo de los inputs, si borraba un campo se volvia a demarcar el botón @Mauricio Contreras

Comment: Entiendo recién a lo que te refieres. En cuanto pueda editaré la respuesta.

Comment: @Miguel acabo de editar mi respuesta, no había leído tu comentario porque no me llamaste a mi con `@MauricioContreras` sino que invocaste a otro usuario que se llama `@Mauricio`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo un montón de cosas extrañas. Has anidado todo el código, así que el checkbox no tendrá evento asignado hasta que alguien pulse una tecla en los input.

Yo lo separaría y lo dejaría así:

```
$('#infoEquipo > div > div > div > input, textarea').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        empty = true;
    } else {
        empty = false;
    }
    alternate(empty);
});

$("#micheckbox334").on("click", function(){

    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        empty = true;
    } else {
        empty = false;
    }

    alternate(empty);
});

function alternate(empty) {
    if (empty) {
        $('#llamada223').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    } else {
        $('#llamada223').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, estoy haciendo cosas muy raras por que intento aprender a base de practica y error por eso salen las cosas así jajajja, gracias!

Comment: todos hemos pasado por el aprendizaje. Animos :)

Comment: probe tu comentario pero el checkbox no lo tiene en cuenta, además de que cada vez que escribo en un `input` se activa el botón hasta que salo de el @Mork